# Using Double buffer with VCL controls

Tags: delphi, doublebuffered, jvcl

My Application have many graphics and visual components... So i switched on doublebufferd = true in each and every components as possible.

later i wanted to use a panel in order to hold some components( it makes alignment easy)
but at the same time the panel must have a transparent property (then only i can show the graphics beneath the panel  )

so i found a panel 'TJVPanel' in my pallet with transparent property so i used it ,and set transparent = true ; align = right (alright)  ;

every thing is ok but when i was resizing, components inside the jvpanel and jvpanel are flicking

so i searched for  doublebufferd but not succeeded

can anyone tell me solution for this or recommend me another component
,but i prefer using jvpanel with some modification

Comment: if you recommend me a vcl please make sure it is free or not

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention flicking , but now i have edited it , once again sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried overriding the OnPaint method of your jvPanel so it paints nothing.  You may have to get it to paint the child controls inside by passing them Paint messages or calling their Paint method.

I haven't done this for a while but it may point you in the right direction.

Comment: I am assuming your components are flickering when you resize your panel.  There are some words missing in you question that make it a little confusing.  "everything is ok but when I was resizing, components inside the jvpanel and jvpanel are ???????"  I am guessing you wanted to replace the last three words with the word "flickering" ?  Is this correct ?

Comment: http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Graphics/VCLRTL.htm - This page makes the following comment.  I have not tested it.

ControlStyle : To prevent the form from repainting its background every time it does a paint, which can cause flicker even when using the double buffering trick, put the following in the FormCreate:
Form1.ControlStyle := Form1.ControlStyle + [csOpaque];

There are many other useful hints on this page.

Answer (score 0):

There some tms components with transparency but you have to pay ,